# Replacing labels in EPS file by LaTeX - text not where it should be

Tags: psfrag

I am spawning a `.eps` file with [`octave`](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) by using this `.m` file:

```
function dummy
xlim([0 81]);
x = [0:0.01:81];
y=x.^0.5+x.^0.4+x.^0.3+x.^0.2+x.^0.1;
plot (x,y*1.85,"-;aaaa;",'linewidth',2,x,y*1.00,"-;bbbb;",'linewidth',2,x,y*1.25,"-;cccc;",'linewidth',2,x,x/2,"-;dddd;",'linewidth',2);
legend ("location", "northwest");
xlabel ("kkkk");
ylabel ("yyyy");
set (gca (), "xtick",[]);
set (gca (), "ytick",[]);
set (gca (), "fontname","DejaVuSans");
print('-dtex', 'dummy.tex');
endfunction
```

and including it with this LaTeX "container":

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx,color}
\thispagestyle{empty}

    % You can run this by typing the following commands:
    %    latex 2dplot.tex
    %    dvips -o 2dplot.ps 2dplot.dvi

\begin{document}

% The syntax of the "psfrag" command is:
%    \psfrag{tag}[<posn>][<psposn>][<scale>][<rot>]{replacement}
% See the file pfgguide.ps for full documentation.

\begin{figure}
\psfrag{aaaa}{\small{$y$}}
\psfrag{bbbb}{\small{$s_1 \cdot y$}}
\psfrag{cccc}{\small{$s_2 \cdot y$}}
\psfrag{dddd}{\small{$k(\Sigma + n + g)$}}
\psfrag{kkkk}{\small{$k$}}
\psfrag{yyyy}{\small{$y$}}
\includegraphics{dummy.eps}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

But the `psfrag` replacements show up at bottom left corner of the page.
Running `latex ./dummy.tex` does not yield any errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The replacements not showing on the actual picture are OK. From the `psfrag` manual:

> When viewing the output with a DVI
>   previewer such as `dviwin` or `xdvi`,
>   a vertical list of the replacements
>   will be placed on the left side of
>   each figure. This list allows you to
>   check the typesetting of your
>   replacements; it disappears in the
>   final PostScript version.
>   Unfortunately, DVI drivers are
>   incapable of *placing* the PSfrag
>   replacements on top of the figure, so
>   for that you will need to print it or
>   use a PostScript previewer like
>   GhostView

You should convert your `dvi` to `ps` or `pdf` or print it in order for the replacements to apply.

Comment: You'll also see the same behavior when using TikZ or pstricks to draw images with TeX text included in the image. A DVI previewer won't position the text properly, but a postscript or PDF version will be fine. This is due to the limitations of the DVI previewers.

Answer (score 2):

As for an alternative to Octave, here is how I would do in R:

```
x <- seq(0, 81, by=.01)
y <- x^.5+x^.4+x^.3+x^.2+x^.1
dat <- data.frame(x, y1=y*1.85, y2=y, y3=y*1.25, y4=x/2)

library(lattice)
lp <- xyplot(y1+y2+y3+y4~x, dat, type="l", xlab="k", ylab="y",
             main="Tour title here",
             col = c('blue', 'red', 'green', 'cyan'),
             key=list(x=0.05, y=0.95, text=list(c(expression(y), 
                                                  expression(s[1] %.% y), 
                                                  expression(s[2] %.% y), 
                                                  expression(k(Sigma + n + g)))),
                      lines=list(lty=1, col=c('blue','red','green','cyan'))))
```

It can be saved as PDF with

```
pdf("yourfilename.pdf", width=5, height=5)
print(lp)
dev.off()
```

or quite in the same manner with the `postscript()` function for EPS output.

Here is the result:

[image]

Comment: ocatve is not capable of inserting greek letters and fun, therefore I wanted to replace the dummy labels aaaa, bbbb and so on with the correct greek formule

Comment: @drahnr I missed that point. Would you like me to give you the R syntax for producing such a plot?

Comment: even if I use your `print(...)` , I still get the PSfrag replacments all rendered at the bottom right of the dvi and the legend gets not adjusted as desired

Comment: give me whatever you have :> I am thankful for everything, maybe point me to a R howto :) thank you

Comment: @drahnr When I generated the pdf, I removed every psfrag commands.

Comment: @drahnr Done. I hope you'll manage to achieve what you want with the above R code. You'll find more help on R plotting on [Quick-R](http://www.statmethods.net/graphs/) or [Graphics with R](http://csg.sph.umich.edu/docs/R/graphics-1.pdf), for a first start.

Comment: can I somehow hide the scale and the dics at the axes?

Comment: @drahnr Sure. Add `scales=list(alternating=0, tck=c(0,0))` in the arguments.

Comment: @chl: If you figure out that your original answer was wrong (I'm not saying it is), simply replace it with the correct one. There is no reason to keep it around and just append the correct one. The history of your edits are saved so nothing is getting lost.

Comment: @Martin Now that I see @fabikw provided a more relevant answer (it didn't work for me, though), I think I will just delete the first part of my response, and make this a CW answer as this now has (obviously) nothing to do with the question :-)

Comment: @drahnr While we're in (and because I read another comment of yours), you can change line thickness with `lwd=` ($>1$ means larger) and line type with `lty=` (1=solid, 2=dashed, 3=dotted, 4=dash-and-dot). It might help if this is for a BW paper. Be sure to add this in both the legend (inside the `key` list) and the call to `xyplot`. Should you want to add a grid layout, use `type=c("l", "g")`. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Generally, I'd be inclined to alter a graphic item by altering the code that created it.  If that cannot be done, I'd use inkscape on it.  These two options yield a graphic that can be used in any application (e.g. presentation application, web application), and not just in latex.  So, heresy that this may be in this group, I'd advise dropping your work with psfrag, seeing as you've had difficulties.

Comment: Postprocessing with inkscape is uggly, in case the grpahs change in the future I'll have to redo it anytime even only a tiny bit changes. Not an option. It is for a paper so..